# obtain elements of array in column based on the values of element in a different array in another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following data set in pandas.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

events = ['event1', 'event2', 'event3', 'event4', 'event5', 'event6']

wells = [np.array([1, 2]), np.array([1, 3]), np.array([1]),
 np.array([4, 5, 6]), np.array([4, 5, 6]), np.array([7, 8])]

traces_per_well = [np.array([24, 24]), np.array([24, 21]), np.array([18]),
 np.array([24, 24, 24]), np.array([24, 21, 24]), np.array([18, 21])]

df = pd.DataFrame({"event_no": events, "well_array": wells,
  "trace_per_well": traces_per_well})

df["total_traces"] = df['trace_per_well'].apply(np.sum)

df['supposed_traces_no'] = df['well_array'].apply(lambda x: len(x)*24)

df['pass'] = df['total_traces'] == df['supposed_traces_no']
print(df)
```

the output is printed below:

```
  event_no well_array trace_per_well  total_traces  supposed_traces_no   pass
0   event1     [1, 2]       [24, 24]            48                  48   True
1   event2     [1, 3]       [24, 21]            45                  48  False
2   event3        [1]           [18]            18                  24  False
3   event4  [4, 5, 6]   [24, 24, 24]            72                  72   True
4   event5  [4, 5, 6]   [24, 21, 24]            69                  72  False
5   event6     [7, 8]       [18, 21]            39                  48  False
```

I want to create two new columns in which the item of numpy array from column `trace_per_well` when it is not equal to 24 will be put in one column and  the corresponding array element from column `well_array` in another column

The result should look like this.

```
  event_no well_array trace_per_well  total_traces  supposed_traces_no   pass wrong_trace_in_well wrong_well
0   event1     [1, 2]       [24, 24]            48                  48   True                 NaN        NaN
1   event2     [1, 3]       [24, 21]            45                  48  False                  21          3
2   event3        [1]           [18]            18                  24  False                  18          1
3   event4  [4, 5, 6]   [24, 24, 24]            72                  72   True                 NaN        NaN
4   event5  [4, 5, 6]   [24, 21, 24]            69                  72  False                  21          5
5   event6     [7, 8]       [18, 21]            39                  48  False            (18, 21)     (7, 8)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with a list comprehension. Generate your result in a single pass of the data and then assign to appropriate columns.

```
v = pd.Series(
        [list(zip(*((x, y) for x, y in zip(X, Y) if x != 24))) 
            for X, Y in zip(df['trace_per_well'], df['well_array'])])

df['wrong_trace_in_well'] = v.str[0]
df['wrong_well'] = v.str[-1]
```

```
df[['wrong_trace_in_well', 'wrong_well']]

  wrong_trace_in_well wrong_well
0                 NaN        NaN
1               (21,)       (3,)
2               (18,)       (1,)
3                 NaN        NaN
4               (21,)       (5,)
5            (18, 21)     (7, 8)
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to do this in multiple passes, then

```
df['wrong_trace_in_well'] = [[x for x in X if x != 24] for X in df['trace_per_well']]
df['wrong_well'] = [
    [y for x, y in zip(X, Y) if x != 24] 
        for X, Y in  zip(df['trace_per_well'], df['well_array'])]
```

```
df[['wrong_trace_in_well', 'wrong_well']]

  wrong_trace_in_well wrong_well
0                  []         []
1                [21]        [3]
2                [18]        [1]
3                  []         []
4                [21]        [5]
5            [18, 21]     [7, 8]
```

Comment: Damn that is elegant.

Comment: @VishnuKunchur Thanks ;-)

Comment: Wow, It is hard for a newbie like me to comprehend your answer but it is working like a charm. really genius and the answer within a minute. Thank you very much, really appreciate your help.

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti Let me know if there's any way I can explain or help you understand. Just ask if there's something you don't follow.

Comment: @coldspeed thank you very much, your answer suffice all I need. I try to scratch my head till getting bold until understanding your answer. maybe one day i will be hotspeed in programming!!